# Repeat the footnote as a header and footnote on next pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, header-footer

I am quite new with Latex, and I am trying to solve a problem but I can't on my own. The thing is that I am editing a document, and I'd like that in that document, there are a header and "footnote" as a drawing. I manage to do it but just on the first page. On the next pages, I'd like that both the header and the foornote is the same figure that the footnote of the first page. Could I do this? How? Here you can have a look to the code. I also attach a image as *a image worth a thousand words* [image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\RequirePackage{tikz}


\tikzstyle{cajanaranja}=[rectangle, fill=orange, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=.15cm]

\tikzstyle{cajagris}=[rectangle, fill=gray, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=3cm]

\tikzstyle{cajanaranjaabajo}=[rectangle, fill=orange, anchor=south, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=.15cm]

\tikzstyle{cajagrisabajo}=[rectangle, fill=gray, anchor=south, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=.15cm]

\newcommand{\header}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [cajanaranja] (boxorange) at (current page.north){};
        \node [cajagris] (boxgray) at (boxorange.south){};
        \node [cajagrisabajo] (boxgraydown) at (current page.south){};
        \node [cajanaranjaabajo] (boxorangedown) at (boxgraydown.north){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1.5cm}
  \vspace{-3\parskip}
}


\begin{document}


\header

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  just a note about terminology.  what you want is a "footer", not a "footnote".  a *footnote* is text that is linked to a reference elsewhere on a page; it is rare that the same footnote occurs on multiple pages.  a *footer*, or *page footer*, is an element that occurs in the same style on almost all pages of a document; the first page of an article or chapter is the usual exception.

Comment: I am sorry, it was a fault of my English. I wasn't totally sure that footnote was the apropiate word, but I didn't know the word and I thought that footnote could make clear what I mean. In my case, I want to use the footer of the first page, as the header and footer of the next pages of the document.

Comment: not a problem.  many tex users (perhaps even most) didn't grow up speaking english.  we'll help if we can.  if you change the question to use the more common term, it might attract more attention.  (you can always edit your own questions.)

Answer (score 1):

With package `scrlayer-scrpage` it would be possible to define a new layer that inserts the pictures at top and bottom in the background of the pages. Then you can add this layer to every page style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\tikzset{
  margins/.style={rectangle,anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=.15cm,outer sep=0pt},
  cajanaranja/.style={margins, fill=orange},
  cajagris/.style={margins,fill=gray,minimum height=3cm},
  %cajanaranjaabajo/.style={margins, fill=orange},
  cajagrisabajo/.style={margins, fill=gray}
}

\newsavebox\firstheader
\savebox\firstheader{\tikz{
  \node [cajanaranja] (boxorange){};
  \node [cajagris] (boxgray) at (boxorange.south){};
}}
\newsavebox\headerorfooter
\savebox\headerorfooter{\tikz{
  \node [cajanaranja] (boxorange){};
  \node [cajagrisabajo] (boxgray) at (boxorange.south){};
}}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  mode=picture,
  contents={
  \ifnum \value{page}=1
  \putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\usebox\firstheader}}
  \else
  \putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\usebox\headerorfooter}}
  \fi
  \putLL{\usebox\headerorfooter}}
]{margins.bg}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{margins.bg}


\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]